# Error: found in Chart.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat, logstash

Tags: elastic-stack

I would like to deploy elastic-stack into Kubernetes cluster. I git clone the chart, use default settings. But, I got errors.

1. git clone https://github.com/helm/charts
2. Create namespace

   kubectl create namespace elastic-stack
3. At $HOME/charts

$ helm install elastic-stack stable/elastic-stack --namespace=elastic-stack

Error: found in Chart.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat, logstash, fluentd, fluent-bit, fluentd-elasticsearch, nginx-ldapauth-proxy, elasticsearch-curator, elasticsearch-exporter

helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.3.0-rc.1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you enabled the stable repo for helm ? you can check this by running `helm repo list`

If not, please add using `helm repo add stable https://charts.helm.sh/stable`